# Encoding issues in browser but NOT in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, configuration, encoding, console

Another **Rails 3 encoding issue** for ya'll.

I have this code in a controller:

```
@page_title = @episode.podcast.name + " &raquo; " + @episode.title.force_encoding("utf-8").truncate(25)
```

When I load the page in the browser I get this error:

```
**incompatible character encodings: ASCII-8BIT and UTF-8**
```

However, when I run the same code in rails console, I get this:

```
"Jenner y Balmís, médic..."
```

My limited knowledge tells me this is related to a configuration or environmental issue.

Answer (score 1):

Are you specifying the characterset in a meta tag in your layout? This is one from a multilingual project I did. Its using HAML but you get the idea:

```
%meta{ :"http-equiv" => "Content-Type", :content => "text/html; charset=utf-8" }
```

Comment: Hmm, I haven't played to much with encoding stuff. I did a little reading and found this though: http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/194493

Comment: Thanks Mike, that article helped me.